# Delphi XE8 android app is not detecting Samsung Note 4

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe8

I have Delphi XE8. Also JDK, SDK and NDK are already installed. I followed all the steps defined in below link. Still my mobile project is not detecting my Samsung Note 4. BTW my development environment is in VM. But my VM is able to detect phone directories when ever I connect note 4 to laptop using USB.

Both my phone and Android SDK are 5.1.1

[Mobile Tutorial: Set Up Your Development Environment on Windows PC (Android)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Set_Up_Your_Development_Environment_on_Windows_PC_(Android))

Any sugesstion what else I might be missing .

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are install SDK new version.(version 24)